# Securely passing parameters to Powershell scripts executed with Puppet?

Tags: powershell, puppet

We have a Puppet module which defines a number of parameters. In this instance, they include a username and password which we don't want to store in the puppet module itself.

Is there a way to pass these parameters into a powershell script which we have in the module directory?

What we have at the moment is:

```
class OurCompany::server($username, $password) {
  exec { 'Change Service Credentials':
    command   => template('OurCompany/OurTemplatedPowerShell.ps1'),
    provider  => powershell,
    logoutput => true,
    returns   => [0, 1]
  }
```

But is it possible to append the parameters to the command?  We've tried things like:

```
class OurCompany::server($username, $password) {      
  exec { 'Change Service Credentials':
    command   => template('OurCompany/OurTemplatedPowerShell.ps1 -Username $username -Password $password'),
    provider  => powershell,
    logoutput => true,
    returns   => [0, 1]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Passing Parameters

The way you are doing it will not work, because the template only accepts the path to a file (same with `file()`).

If you are looking to pass parameters to a PowerShell file, there is a much simpler option here.

You should rename the PowerShell file to `OurTemplatedPowerShell.ps1.erb` (not that it is required, but it helps identify it better). Then in the file itself, you should add the following right near the top:

```
$UsernameERB = '<%= @username %>'
$PasswordERB = '<%= @password %>'

if ($UsernameERB -ne $null -and $UsernameERB -ne '') {
  $Username = $UsernameERB
}

if ($PasswordERB -ne $null -and $PasswordERB -ne '') {
  $Password = $PasswordERB
}
```

In this way you can support running the script outside of Puppet and with Puppet with fewer changes.

Now change your manifest to simply this:

```
class OurCompany::server($username, $password) {
  exec { 'Change Service Credentials':
    command   => template('OurCompany/OurTemplatedPowerShell.ps1.erb'),
    provider  => powershell,
    logoutput => true,
    returns   => [0, 1]
  }
```

The values are passed to the bindings for the ERB automatically. It makes passing values through much simpler.

If you need to see an example of this, take a look at

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-chocolatey/blob/2862e058de0c28be363cb7df03aa5da31caae414/templates/InstallChocolatey.ps1.erb#L24

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-chocolatey/blob/2862e058de0c28be363cb7df03aa5da31caae414/manifests/install.pp#L11-L18

It looks like the values are magic, but they are passed through to ruby templates (ERB) based on Puppet variables, so `$username` (Puppet manifest) == `@username` (in ERB file).

### Encryption

Your best bet for now is going to be this: https://github.com/TomPoulton/hiera-eyaml

There is something similar upcoming from Puppet for the Puppet Data Provider, but that is not going to be production ready until probably Puppet 5.

Store your password inside the hieradata like:

```
username: username
password: password
```

and use the `hiera-eyaml` to encrypt it.  Look it up inside your manifest like:

```
class OurCompany::server($username = hiera('username'), $password = hiera('password')) {
```

You can also use automatic parameter lookup/automatic data bindings if you are only going to use the username and password inside this manifest:

```
# hieradata
---
OurCompany::server::username: username
OurCompany::server::password: password
```

Then you don't have to use hiera functions inside your manifest.

Comment: just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of passing parameters;

```
class OurCompany::server($username, $password) {
  exec { 'Change Service Credentials':
    command   => epp('OurCompany/OurTemplatedPowerShell.ps1', { parameter1 => $username, parameter2 => $password }),  
    provider  => powershell,  
    logoutput => true,  
    returns   => [0, 1],  
}
```

obviously your epp file would have to define parameter1 and parameter2 at the top.
the OurCompany/templates/OurTemplatedPowerShell.ps1 epp in the module would be something like;

```
<%- | String $parameter1, $parameter2 | -%>

$User = '<%= $parameter1 %>'
$Password = '<%= $parameter2 %>'
.....MORE POWERSHELL TO DO WHAT YOU WANT.....
```